# Unremovable patches of dirt?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've removed many player-made patches of dirt (from removed projects), but I'm wondering if there are un-removable patches of dirt in my town. Are there unremovable patches of dirt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All dirt can host grass on top of it unless it's under a building. All visible dirt will, given the correct methods, be able to regrow grass.

So **no**, there are **no permanent dirt patches**.